# Recover hard disk damaged by overwritten with dd

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery

My hard drive with GPT format was overwritten by accident. I ran `dd` over it when I tried to write an .iso to an USB memory.

`$ dd if=Ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sda`

Then I tried to fix my partition table with a Linux live and gdisk but didn't work. I ran:

`$ gdisk
   r   # recover and transformation option
   b  # use backup GPT header
   c  # load backup partition from disk
   w # write table to disk and exit`

Now I can't mount any filesystem. When I run `mount /dev/sda6 /mnt` I get:

`Mount: /dev/sda6 is already mounted or /mnt busy`

I'd like at least mount the filesystem to save my data to a backup.

Comment: Take the disk out, put another disk in. Install Ubuntu on the new disk. Put the old disk in an external case. Make an image of that disk to a third disk, or - much better - write it to an iso-file. Then mount that third disk, mess with it, do what you need. Don't touch the original disk anymore. Next: make a backup!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: It's a large amount of data. The hard drive is 1TB capacity. Would I need a larger amount of storage to write an .iso, right?

Comment: If money isn't a problem, buy a 3 or 4TB disk, and after solving these problems, this will be your backup disk. You can get 3TB 2.5" drives for a reasonable price. That gives you enough space. I can recommend the Photorec program from one of the answers of the duplicate link above. After formatting an Ext4 disk to NTFS I could still get most data off that disk. When the partition table is gone, filenames and dates are gone, but unless the data is overwritten, the files are still there.